How to use Date labels as Y axis in chartsjs
Given the following chart how can I show a custom HTML label for the Y ticks?
  const yAxisLabelsLookup = {
    0: {
      label: '2024-01-01',
      color: 'red',
    },
    1: {
      label: '2024-01-02',
      color: 'blue',
    },
    2: {
      label: '2024-01-03',
      color: 'green',
    },
    3: {
      label: '2024-01-04',
      color: 'yellow',
    },
  }
  const ctx = document.getElementById('chart-container');

  const data = {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'First Dataset',
      data: [
        {
          x: 20,
          y: 0,
          r: 15
        }, {
          x: 40,
          y: 0,
          r: 10
        },
        {
          x: 20,
          y: 1,
          r: 10
        },
        {
          x: 40,
          y: 1,
          r: 10
        },
        {
          x: 25,
          y: 2,
          r: 10
        },
        {
          x: 35,
          y: 2,
          r: 10
        },
      ],
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
    }]
  };

  const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bubble',
    data: data,
    options: {
      // So we can set the height with css.
      // maintainAspectRatio: false,
      responsive: true,
      scales: {
        x: {
          type: 'time',
          // time: {
          //   displayFormats: {
          //     quarter: 'MMM YYYY'
          //   }
          // }
          position: 'top',
          ticks: {
            padding: 15,
          },
        },
        y: {
          // display: false,
          ticks: {
            padding: 25,
            callback: function (value) {
              if (value in yAxisLabelsLookup) {
                const label = yAxisLabelsLookup[value].label;
                const color = yAxisLabelsLookup[value].color;
                return `<span style="color: ${color};">${label}</span>`;
              } else {
                // Return the default numeric value if no custom label is found
                return value;
              }
              // if (value in dateLookupMap) {
              //   return dateLookupMap[value]
              // } else {
              //   return ''
              // }
            }
          }
        },
      }
    }
  });


chart.js uses canvas to render charts; you can't return html to format stuff inside the chart.
All available options
are to be set through the configuration object.
Some options are scriptable,
which means that the value can be a function, that will be called only when the option is needed and
should return the actual value of the option based on the context, in a similar way to what callback does for
tick labels text.
The tick label color can be set through options.scales.y.ticks.color, programmatically if needed since it is
scriptable. Similarly, you may use options.scales.y.ticks.font to set other visual properties of labels like size or weight.
Your code could thus be changed to:
   options: {
       // .... other options
       scales: {
         // x ....
          y: {
              ticks: {
                 callback: function (value) {
                    if (value in yAxisLabelsLookup) {
                       return yAxisLabelsLookup[value].label;
                    } else {
                       return value;
                    }
                 },
                 color: function({tick: {value}}){
                    if (value in yAxisLabelsLookup){
                       return yAxisLabelsLookup[value].color;
                    }
                 }
              }
          }
       }
   }

Snippet:


const yAxisLabelsLookup = {
    0: {
        label: '2024-01-01',
        color: 'red',
    },
    1: {
        label: '2024-01-02',
        color: 'blue',
    },
    2: {
        label: '2024-01-03',
        color: 'green',
    },
    3: {
        label: '2024-01-04',
        color: 'yellow',
    },
}

const data = {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'First Dataset',
        data: [
            {
                x: 20,
                y: 0,
                r: 15
            }, {
                x: 40,
                y: 0,
                r: 10
            },
            {
                x: 20,
                y: 1,
                r: 10
            },
            {
                x: 40,
                y: 1,
                r: 10
            },
            {
                x: 25,
                y: 2,
                r: 10
            },
            {
                x: 35,
                y: 2,
                r: 10
            },
        ],
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
    }]
};
const chart = new Chart('chart-container', {
    type: 'bubble',
    data: data,
    options: {
        // So we can set the height with css.
        // maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'time',
                // time: {
                //   displayFormats: {
                //     quarter: 'MMM YYYY'
                //   }
                // }
                position: 'top',
                ticks: {
                    padding: 15,
                },
            },
            y: {
                ticks: {
                    padding: 25,
                    callback: function (value) {
                        if (value in yAxisLabelsLookup) {
                            return yAxisLabelsLookup[value].label;
                        } else {
                            return value;
                        }
                    },
                    color: function({tick: {value}}){
                        if (value in yAxisLabelsLookup){
                            return yAxisLabelsLookup[value].color
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    }
});
<div style="max-height: 400px">
    <canvas id="chart-container"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.4.2/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>




I added just one example about the customizing label of the chart. I added one link, you can follow.
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scale-options/ticks.html
const DATA_COUNT = 12;
const NUMBER_CFG = {count: DATA_COUNT, min: 0, max: 100};
const data = {
  labels: [['June', '2015'], 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', ['January', '2016'], 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      data: Utils.numbers(NUMBER_CFG),
      fill: false,
      borderColor: Utils.CHART_COLORS.red,
      backgroundColor: Utils.transparentize(Utils.CHART_COLORS.red, 0.5),
    },
    {
      label: 'Dataset 2',
      data: Utils.numbers(NUMBER_CFG),
      fill: false,
      borderColor: Utils.CHART_COLORS.blue,
      backgroundColor: Utils.transparentize(Utils.CHART_COLORS.blue, 0.5),
    }
  ]
};
    const config = {
      type: 'line',
      data: data,
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Chart with Tick Configuration'
          }
        },
        scales: {
          x: {
            ticks: {
              // For a category axis, the val is the index so the lookup via getLabelForValue is needed
              callback: function(val, index) {
                // Hide every 2nd tick label
                return index % 2 === 0 ? this.getLabelForValue(val) : '';
              },
              color: 'red',
            }
          }
        }
      },
    };

